# How can I parallelize this factorial code to be more efficient?

Tags: java, factorial

I have written this piece of code for computing the factorial of any number that it starts to become slow when the input is about one million or higher.

How can I parallelize it to be more efficient?

I haven't studied parallelization of programs.

```
package programas;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IterativeFactorial {

  public BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    if ( n == null ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else if ( n.signum() == - 1 ) {
      // negative
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument must be a non-negative integer");
    }
    else {
      BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.ONE;
      for ( BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(n) < 1; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE) ) {
        factorial = factorial.multiply(i);
      }
      return factorial;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigInteger number, result;
    boolean error = false;
    System.out.println("FACTORIAL OF A NUMBER");
    do {
      System.out.println("Enter a number:");
      try {
        number = scanner.nextBigInteger();
        result = new IterativeFactorial().factorial(number);
        error = false;
        System.out.println("Factorial of " + number + ": " + result);
      }
      catch ( InputMismatchException e ) {
        error = true;
        scanner.nextLine();
      }

      catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
        error = true;
        scanner.nextLine();
      }
    }
    while ( error );
    scanner.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Are allowed to use something like `Stream` API? Or must you implement the parallelization your self?

Comment: I can do it in both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to achieve easy parallelization of the computations by using reduction.

> A reduction operation (also called a fold) takes a sequence of input elements and combines them into a single summary result by repeated application of a combining operation, such as finding the sum or maximum of a set of numbers, or accumulating elements into a list.

Above is from the [package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), take a read for more in-depth information.

```
BigInteger num = scanner.nextBigInteger();
BigInteger result = Stream.iterate(BigInteger.TWO, bi -> bi.compareTo(num) <= 0, bi -> bi.add(BigInteger.ONE))
        .parallel()
        .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
System.out.println(result);
```

1. [Stream.iterate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) will create a stream equivalent to looping from 2 to input number inclusive. Starting from 2, because `1 * 1 = 1`, no point in doing this operation.
2. [parallel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) will parallelize the stream, otherwise it will be sequential, same as the loop.
3. [reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) will reduce the stream to a single value, starting from 1, by multiplying all elements.